# Writing a single NCDF4 file with variables extracted from 159 separate NCDF4 files

Tags: r

I have a 159 Ncdf4 files with 56 ensembles in each file. I want to pull out ensemble 1 from each of the 159 input files. Then  produce a single NCDF4 file with all the ensemble 1  in a single file. My code is below. My problem is that only data the last file of the 159 is written to the output file. I think I am missing a nested loop, but not sure and my attempts have failed.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(ncdf.tools)
library(ncdf4)
library(ncdf4.helpers)
library(RNetCDF)

setwd("D:/Rwork/Project")   # set working folder

#####Write NCDF4 files#############################################
dir("D:/Rwork/Project/Test")->xlab # This is the directory where the file for analysising are
filelist <- paste("Test/",dir("Test"),sep="")


N <- length(filelist)     # Loop over the individual files
for(j in 1:N){
  
    File<-nc_open(filelist[j])
    print(filelist[j])  
    Temperature<-ncvar_get(File,"t2m")
    Lat<-ncvar_get(File, "lat")
    Lon<-ncvar_get(File,"lon")
    Time<-ncvar_get(File,"time")
    EnsambleNo.<-ncvar_get(File,"ensemble_member")
    Temperature
    Ensamble1<-Temperature[,,1,] #The Ensamble wanted, 1 to 56
    Ensamble1<-round(Ensamble1,digits = 0)

    tunits<-"hours since 1800-01-01 00:00:00"

    #Define dimensions
    ##################################################################
    londim<-ncdim_def("Lon","degrees_east",as.double(Lon))
    latdim<-ncdim_def("Lat", "degrees_north",as.double(Lat))
    timedim<-ncdim_def("Time",tunits,as.double(Time))

    #Define variables
    ##################################################################
    fillvalue<-1e32

    dlname<-"tm2"

    tmp_def<-ncvar_def("Ensamble1","deg_K", list(londim,latdim,timedim),fillvalue,dlname,prec =       "double")

    ncfname<-("D:/Rwork/Project/TrialEnsamble/TrialEnsamble.nc")
    ncout<-nc_create(ncfname,list(tmp_def),force_v4=T)

    ncvar_put(ncout,tmp_def,Ensamble1,start=NA,count = NA )# Think I need a  nested loop here


    ncatt_put(ncout,"Lon","axis","X")
    ncatt_put(ncout, "Lat", "axis", "Y")
    ncatt_put(ncout, "Time","axis", "T")

    title<-c( 1:2 )
    names(title)<-c("Ian","Gillespie")
    title<-as.data.frame(title)

    ncatt_put(ncout,0,"Make_NCDF4_File",1, prec="int")
    ncatt_put(ncout,0,"Maynooth_University",1,prec="short")
    ncatt_put(ncout,0,"AR000087828",1, prec="short")
    ncatt_put(ncout,0,"mickymouse",1, prec="short")

    history <- paste("P.J. Bartlein", date(), sep=", ")
    ncatt_put(ncout,0,"description","this is the script to write NCDF4 files")

    #Close file and write date to disk
     ##########################################################
    nc_close(ncout)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it is better to prepare an empty array of four dimensions with the first 3 the same size and names dimensions as the array produced from the for loop with an additional fourth dimension. The forth dimension to hold the results of each iteration
dir("D:/Rwork/Project/Test")->xlab # This is the directory where the file for analysising are
   filelist <- paste("Test/",dir("Test"),sep="")

```
output <- array(, dim=c(192,94,12,160))# need to change this to   length(Lat), etc

N <- length(filelist)     # Loop over the individual files
for(j in 1:N){

  File<-nc_open(filelist[j])
  print(filelist[j])  
  Temperature<-ncvar_get(File,"t2m")
  Lat<-ncvar_get(File, "lat")
  Lon<-ncvar_get(File,"lon")
  Time<-ncvar_get(File,"time")
  Year<-c(1851:2010)
  EnsambleNo.<-ncvar_get(File,"ensemble_member")
  Temperature
  Lat<-round(Lat,digits = 2)
  Lon<-round(Lon,digits = 2)
  Ensamble1<-Temperature[,,1,] #The Ensamble wanted, 1 to 56
  Ensamble1<-round(Ensamble1,digits = 1)
  dimnames(Ensamble1)<-list(Lon,Lat,Time)
  dimnames(output) <- list(Lon,Lat,Time,Year)
  }

  print(Ensamble1)
```